# How to find a sequence of chars (ignoring characters in between) in a string (JAVA)

Tags: java, string

I have to make a algorithm that find how many repetitions are of the sequence SUN in a given string.

The sequence must contain the characters S-U-N in that order, even with other characters between them, then that counts toward its SUN degree. Each occurrence of SUN increases the degree by 1. For instance, the sequences GUSN, GSUN, and SSRUUWN have SUN degrees of 0, 1, and 4, respectively.

It must follow this things:

1> First receive a T integer number of cases. 1≤T≤1000 //assumed

2> Every single time the program receives a string and calculate the degree (repetitions) of the sequence. 1≤|string|≤1000 //assumed

**Sample Input:**

3

GUSN

GSUN

SSRUUWN

**Sample Output:**

0

1

4

I already did the program, **the problem is that its too slow.**

This is my program so far:

**UPDATED**

public class Solution {

```
private static Scanner STDIN = new Scanner(System.in);

private static int t = 0;


/**
 * Sets value of t.
 */
public static void setT(int k){
    t=k+1;
}

/**
 * Gets repetitions (degree) of the sequence CAT inside a given
 * sequence, no matter if there are another characters in 
 * between.
 * @return degree repetitions of the sequence
 */
public static long getDegree(String sequence){
    long degree = 0;

    char[] sequenceChars = new char[t];
    sequenceChars = sequence.toCharArray();

    for(int i=0; i<sequenceChars.length; i++){
        if(sequenceChars[i]=='S'){
            for(int n=i+1; n<sequenceChars.length; n++){
                if(sequenceChars[n]=='U'){
                    for(int k=n+1; k<sequenceChars.length; k++){
                        if(sequenceChars[k]=='N'){
                        degree++;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return degree;

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    int t = STDIN.nextInt();
    setT(t);

    for(int i = 0; i<t; i++){
        String sequence = STDIN.next();
        System.out.println(getDegree(sequence));
    }

}
```

}

**PREVIOUS VERSION**

public class Solution {

```
private static Scanner STDIN = new Scanner(System.in);

/**
 * Gets repetitions (degree) of the sequence SUN inside a given
 * sequence, no matter if there are another characters in 
 * between.
 * @return degree repetitions of the sequence
 */
public static long getDegree(String sequence){
    long degree = 0;

    for(int i=0; i<sequence.length(); i++){
        if(sequence.charAt(i)=='S'){
            for(int n=i+1; n<sequence.length(); n++){
                if(sequence.charAt(n)=='U'){
                    for(int k=n+1; k<sequence.length(); k++){
                        if(sequence.charAt(k)=='N'){
                        degree++;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return degree;

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    int t = STDIN.nextInt();

    for(int i = 0; i<t; i++){
        String sequence = STDIN.next();
        System.out.println(getDegree(sequence));
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Convert the string to a char array first. `charAt` is slower than accessing array elements.

Comment: There is no way that the process of getting the degree (by array) could be faster? Because I already tried with the array and still too slow.

Comment: I posted the updated version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a really fast way of doing this.
The array Sa stores at index i, how often the sequence SUN is contained in the substring of the input string starting at i.
Ua stores how often the sequence UN is contained. And Na stores how often N is contained.
This is a form of memoization
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization

```
public static long getDegree(String sequence){
  if(sequence.length() == 0) return 0;
  long degree = 0;
  char[] array = sequence.toCharArray();

  long[] Sa = new long[array.length];
  long[] Ua = new long[array.length];
  long[] Na = new long[array.length];

  if(array[array.length - 1] == 'N') Na[array.length - 1] = 1;
  else Na[array.length - 1] = 0;
  Ua[array.length - 1] = 0;
  Sa[array.length - 1] = 0;

  for(int i = array.length - 2; i >= 0; i--) {
    char c = array[i];
    Na[i] = Na[i + 1] + (c == 'N' ? 1 : 0);
    Ua[i] = Ua[i + 1] + (c == 'U' ? Na[i + 1] : 0);
    Sa[i] = Sa[i + 1] + (c == 'S' ? Ua[i + 1] : 0);
  }
  return Sa[0];
}
```

**edit:**
I noticed you don't even need the arrays. You can make it even faster by replacing them with simple longs.

```
public static long getDegree(String sequence){
  if(sequence.length() == 0) return 0;
  long degree = 0;
  char[] array = sequence.toCharArray();

  long S = 0;
  long U = 0;
  long N = 0;

  for(int i = array.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    char c = array[i];
    S = S + (c == 'S' ? U : 0);
    U = U + (c == 'U' ? N : 0);
    N = N + (c == 'N' ? 1 : 0);
  }
  return S;
}
```

Comment: Ok.. I understood the approach, but I dont really get what the method its returning. Because I put it on test and it returns 0 for everything.

Comment: I also tested it and it works fine. When I give it random input strings it always returns the same result as your method.

Comment: btw. I found another optimization I can make.

Comment: Thank you! Its a great solution.

Answer (score 1):

Using the String method: matches(String regex) might be the most simple solution to this problem.

You could use it in many ways, for example: making a loop where you check for a single occurence of "SUN" and storing ++ value if found, then replacing one instance with String replaceFirst(String regex, String replacement) method to removing one instance from the string being checked.

For usage regarding regex, check the following links:

[Oracle documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#sum)

[Tutorial](http://regexone.com/) (Some expressions may vary between languages, check the above link for confirmation).

Comment: But how this takes into consideration the characters in between?


For example, "SUUSUN" must return 4 repetitions.

Comment: You can essentially use regex to say format: "S.*U.*N", whereas (.*) is any number of any characters from 0 to infinity in between. There are also expressions for "any character except for character x" etc.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have 3 nested loops, the innermost loop is repeating the (almost) same search, over and over again.

Start by parsing the string, eliminating all non-essential letters and collapsing repeated letters:

```
SSRUUWSUNXXS  -->  S(2)  U(2)  S  U  N  S
```

E.g. result of the parse would be a `LetterCount[]`, where class has 2 fields `char letter` and `int count`.

Then you do the triple loop on this optimized sequence, multiplying the counts:

```
  S(2) * U(2) * N(1)
+ S(2) * U(1) * N(1)
+ S(1) * U(1) * N(1)
= 4 + 2 + 1
= 7
```